# Can Power BI Authenticate with LDAP?

Tags: authentication, powerbi, ldap

I actually want to login PowerBI with local Active Directory Authentication. But PowerBI authenticates with Azure Active Directory.

My question is that, If I Sync my Local Active Directory with Azure Active Directory using **Azure Active Directory Connect Tool**, can PowerBI be authenticated locally using Windows Active Directory?

Also, when I embed my powerbi Report into my Internal Web Portal, will the Embedded PowerBI report get **Single-Singned-On**?

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

yes... it can be done but in website we wont get right document kindly configure separately and finally merge both we will